# React useState - strange behaviour with useState and arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Using the example component below, passing the 'setter' from a useState into a child works fine for a string, but not for an array.  It says the setter (for the array only) is 'not a function'.  Using the setter in the parent works well.  Working around it by calling a method in the parent works also, but I don't see why that should be required.

Why does it behave like this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [testString, setTestString] = useState('initial string value');
  const [testSimpleArray, setTestSimpleArray] = useState(['one initial', 'two initial']);

  const handleArrayChange = (arg) => {
    setTestSimpleArray(arg);
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Subcomponent
        testString={testString}
        setTestString={setTestString}
        testSimpleArray={testSimpleArray}
        setSimpleArray={setTestSimpleArray}
        altArrayChanger={handleArrayChange}

      ></Subcomponent>

      <button onClick={() => setTestSimpleArray(['new from parent', 'new two from parent'])}>Set array in parent (works)</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Subcomponent

```
function Subcomponent({testString, setTestString, testSimpleArray, setTestSimpleArray, altArrayChanger}) {
  
  
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <h2>String</h2>
          {testString} <br />
          <button onClick={() => setTestString('boo')}>setting string from subcomponent is ok</button>
        
          <h2>Array</h2>
          {JSON.stringify(testSimpleArray)} <br />
          <button onClick={() => setTestSimpleArray(['new from subcomponent', 'new two from subcomponent'])}>Set array in subcomponent fails</button>

          <button onClick={() => altArrayChanger(['new alt from subcomponent', 'new alt two from subcomponent'])}>Workaround (call parent event to do the update there)</button>

        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  
export default App;
```

Comment: You are passing an argument of `setSimpleArray` to `Subcomponent` where you meant (judging by the name of the parameters passed to the same component) `setTestSimpleArray`. Was that the issue?

Comment: Good pickup, that was an issue with my minimal example.  Leave it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`Subcomponent`  is defined to take a `setTestSimpleArray` prop

```
Subcomponent({
  testString,
  setTestString,
  testSimpleArray,
  setTestSimpleArray, // <--
  altArrayChanger
})
```

But is passed a prop `setSimpleArray` instead

```
<Subcomponent
  testString={testString}
  setTestString={setTestString}
  testSimpleArray={testSimpleArray}
  setSimpleArray={setTestSimpleArray} // <--
  altArrayChanger={handleArrayChange}
/>
```

## Solution

Pass prop correctly

```
<Subcomponent
  testString={testString}
  setTestString={setTestString}
  testSimpleArray={testSimpleArray}
  setTestSimpleArray={setTestSimpleArray} // <--
  altArrayChanger={handleArrayChange}
/>
```

[image: Edit react-usestate-strange-behaviour-with-usestate-and-arrays]

Comment: This was a typo in my minimal example, but certainly correct for the example I provided!  Thanks.